# Top Command not showing stats

Tags: top

I am new to the OS and when I run the TOP command it's not showing me the stats on the TOP.

I ended up installing HTOP but still want to know whats going on with TOP command.

Thanks

Comment: What stat `top` is not showing ?

Comment: I think I found the answer.. for some reason the display color is hiding the output but when I copy paste it I can see the values


top - 01:16:32 up 55 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.34, 0.43, 0.46
Tasks: 271 total,   2 running, 269 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8077964 total,  2908496 used,  5169468 free,   126472 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  1743816 cached Mem

Answer (score 2):

While `top` is running, type <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

If something disappears when you type that letter, type it again...

**LQ reviewers:** That's it!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Not bad, but OP has found his own solution :P :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer while I was trying to copy paste the TOP command output here.

It the Char color was same as background color causing the output to not show.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is showing the stats but its not visible to the naked eye.
You can do the following

1. Go to terminals preferences
2. Choose colors tab
3. Select checkbox for "Use colors from system theme"

You are set.